# It's showing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Tags: java, arrays

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(bo.readLine());
int k = 0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    a[k++] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}//This line is giving exception.


for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {       
   int temp = a[j];
   int temp1 = a[j + 1];
   int num = temp + temp1;
```

I want output for this line.

Comment: How is `a` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases:

- a[k++] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
- int temp1 = a[j + 1];

You are attempting to access `a` without ever making any checks to see if `k` and `j + 1` results in values beyond the size of `a`.

You probably have some code of the sort `int[] a = new int[1];`.

To solve the problem you will need to either:

- Declare a larger array
- Add checks in place to ensure that you never go beyond the limits of `a`:

  - `while (st.hasMoreTokens() && (k < a.length))`
  - `for (int j = 0; ((j < k) && ((j + 1) < a.length); j++) {`

Answer (score 0):

just to be sure, do you initialize the 'a' array in your code... 
and in java you must give the size of the array you are using ... so it may be that the size of the array is small in which the variable k is becoming larger than the last index of the array 'a' so I suggest for you to use arrayList or to use a list in stead of array ...

Answer (score 0):

you must change size of your integer array dynamically
or simply use array list or lists to store integers

use scanner to read user inputs

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
```

this code is using dynamic array

```
StringTokenizer int_string = new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine());
int length = int_string.countTokens();
int integer_array [] = new int[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    integer_array[i] = Integer.parseInt(int_string.nextToken());
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer_array));
```

this code is using array_list

```
StringTokenizer int_string = new StringTokenizer(scanner.nextLine());
ArrayList<Integer> number_list = new ArrayList<>();
while (int_string.hasMoreTokens()) {
    number_list.add(Integer.parseInt(int_string.nextToken()));
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number_list.toArray()));
```

here is sample input in one line as string:

```
10 20 30 40 50 450 6060 50504 989898 56456 20 10100 5460 0365 000
```

and output is :

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 450, 6060, 50504, 989898, 56456, 20, 10100, 5460, 365, 0]
```